# What is a triglyceride?

Tags: nomenclature, biochemistry, chemical-biology

I'm confused on what a triglyceride is, from what my text book it says its a type of gylercide, then from a website it said

> Glycerides can be subdivided into two categories. The first group, the neutral glycerides are nonionic and nonpolar. The second group, the phosphoglycerides contain a polar region, the phosphoryl group.

Which makes triglyceride not a directly under a glyceride but under one of these groups. Then it says

> Esterification may occur at one, two or all three positions producing monoglycerides (monoacylglycerols), diglycerides (diacylglycerols), or triglycerides (triacylglycerols). The most prevalent and most important are the triglycerides.

So does that mean that triglyceride can be produced by either of the two groups phosphoglycerides and neutral glycerides. And if that's correct then how are monoglycerides and diglycerides produced.

[Source](http://www.chem.latech.edu/~deddy/chem121/Lipids.htm/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some minor argument as far as nomenclature goes for these lipids. Most sources I can find, including [IUPAC](http://goldbook.iupac.org/G02647.html) have glycerides as only including esters of glycerol with fatty acids. Monoglycerides have a single fatty acid ester with two free OH groups, diglycerides have two fatty acid esters, and triglycerides have three. Phosphoglycerides are [defined](http://goldbook.iupac.org/P04558.html) separately as esterified derivatives of phosphatidic acids, so you can think of them like glycerides where for one of the substituents, instead of a fatty acid, some derivative of phosphoric acid is present. However, the way the two terms are defined, they don't encompass any common molecules, i.e. there are no molecules that are both glycerides and phosphoglicerides and neither group is a subset of the other.

So: mono-, di-, and triglycerides are subsets of glycerides while phosphoglycerides are a different group altogether, though structurally similar.

Comment: Oh I see that makes sense so phophoglycerides are not a type of glycerin but is completely different from each other and triglycerides are a type of glyercides. That makes so much sense now thank you so much.